# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param()

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Quiero registrar y consultar, pero me sale este error(consultar) y no sé como más hacer.
Ayuda!!

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on bool in D:\Archivos de programa\Xampp\htdocs\Android\Operacion.php:23 Stack trace: #0 D:\Archivos de programa\Xampp\htdocs\Android\RegistrarUsuario.php(17): Operacion->registrarUsuario('', '', '', '', '1') #1 {main} thrown in D:\Archivos de programa\Xampp\htdocs\Android\Operacion.php on line 23
```

**Operacion.php**

```
    <?php
    class Operacion{

            private $con;

        function __construct(){
            require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/BDConeccion.php';
            $bd = new BDConeccion();
            $this->con= $bd->conectar();            
        }

        function __destruct(){

        }
        function registrarUsuario($dni, $nombre, $usuario, $password, $idRol){          


            $stmt = $this->con->prepare
            ("INSERT INTO datos (`dni`, `nombre`, `usuario`, `password`, `idRol`) 
            VALUES  (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

            $stmt->bind_param('isssi',
                $dni, 
                $nombre, 
                $usuario, 
                $password, 
                $idRol
            );

            $stmt->execute();
            if ($stmt === false) {
                return [ 'ok' => 'false' ];
            } else {
                return [ 'ok' => 'true' ];
            }
        }
        function imprimirVariable($variable){
            echo ("Valor de la variable:".$variable);
        }
    }
?>
```

**RegistrarUsuarios.php**

```
    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
    require_once './Operacion.php';     
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
            if (isset($_POST['dni']) and isset($_POST['nombre']) 
            and isset($_POST['usuario']) and isset($_POST['password']) 
            and isset($_POST['idRol'])){

                $bd = new Operacion();

                if ($bd->registrarUsuario(
                    $_POST['dni'],
                    $_POST['nombre'],
                    $_POST['usuario'],
                    $_POST['password'],
                    $_POST['idRol'])){
                    echo('Se registro');
                }else{
                    echo('No se registro');
                } 
            }else{
                echo('Error de campos');
            }
    }else{
        echo('Petición fuera de orden');
    }
?>
```

Comment: Te esta dando error la consulta. Las comillas simples que tienes en los campos son incorrectas. Cambialas

Answer (score 2):

Cuando un *`prepare`* genera un error en la BBDD el conector mysqli no tira una excepción sino que devuelve `false`.

Cito: https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php

> mysqli_prepare() devuelve un objeto de sentencia o FALSE si ocurre un error.

Por alguna razón tu llamado a `prepare` está generando un error y recibes `false` (booleano)

La manera simple de manejarlo sería: (por ejemplo)

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO datos 
       (`dni`, `nombre`, `usuario`, `password`, `idRol`) 
        VALUES  (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

$stmt = $this->con->prepare($sql) 
        || die( sprintf("Error!: %s", $this->con->error) );
```

Esto es: "devuélveme la sentencia preparada o muere con el mensaje de error".

**Sin embargo** La mejor práctica para manejarlo sería tirar una excepción, porque las excepciones las puedes manejar mientras un `die(...)` es difícil debuggearlo en producción y un no-go para pruebas unitarias.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO datos 
       (`dni`, `nombre`, `usuario`, `password`, `idRol`) 
        VALUES  (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

$stmt = $this->con->prepare($sql);
if( $stmt === false) {
  throw new \Exception(  $this->con->error );
}
// si pasó esta verificación el script sigue como lo tienes hoy
```

Luego en RegistrarUsuarios.php lo llamarías como:

```
try {

        $bd = new Operacion();

        if ($bd->registrarUsuario(...)) {
          ...
        }

} catch (\Exception $e) {

   echo sprintf("Error!: %s", $e->getMessage());

}
```

**Sugerencias:**

**Tienes un error en tu verificación de inserción**. Ésta devuelve un array `['ok' => true ]` o bien `['ok' => false ]`. Luego `if ($bd->registrarUsuario(...)) {...}` siempre se cumple.

**Segundo, mucha anidación innecesaria.** tu código dice:

```js
if ( /* método post */ ) {
   if ( /* campos requeridos en el POST */ ) {
      if ( /* se ejecuta la inserción */ ) {
         echo "todo bien!!";
      } else {
         echo "error insert";
      } 
   } else {
     echo "error campos";
   }
} else {
  echo "error método";   
}
```

Esa anidación te va a pesar en el futuro. No la necesitas:

```js
if (! /* método post */ ) {
  echo "error método";   
  return;
}
if (! /* campos requeridos en el POST */ ) {
  echo "error campos";   
  return;
}

if (! /* se ejecuta la inserción */ ) {
  echo "error insert";   
  return;
}
echo "todo bien!";
return;
```

y si envuelves eso en un un método puedes retornar en vez de imprimir y luego usar un solo echo para imprimir lo que sea que devuelve el método

```js
  class Operacion{

    public function __construct(){
        ...
    }

    public function verificaLuegoInserta() {
      if ( ! /* método POST */ ) {
         return "error método";
      }
      if ( ! /* campos requeridos */ ) {
         return "error campos";
      }
      ... etcétera...
    }
 }


// Y en RegistrarUsuarios 

require_once './Operacion.php';     
echo (new Operacion())->verificaLuegoInserta();
```

Tercero, **si vas a animarte con las excepciones**, aprovéchalas con algo como

```js
 class Operacion{
    
    public function __construct(){
            ...
    }

    public function verificaLuegoInserta($Operacion) {
      if ( ! /* método POST */ ) {
         throw new \Exception("error método");
      }
      if ( ! /* campos requeridos */ ) {
         throw new \Exception("error campos");
      }
      if ( ! $this->registrarUsuario(...)) {
         throw new \Exception("error insercion");
      }
      return "todo bien";
    }
 }

// Y en RegistrarUsuarios

require_once './Operacion.php';     
try {
   echo (new Operacion())->verificaLuegoInserta();
} catch (\Exception $e ) {
   echo sprintf('Algo salió mal: %s', $e->getMessage());
}
```

¿Para qué? Bueno, en este momento siempre terminas imprimiendo un texto y la manera de saber si funciona o no es mirar si ese texto contiene "error". Eso es frágil. Basta que alguien cambie "error" por "falla" por ejemplo y todas las piezas que buscaban la cadena "error" se rompen. Con la excepción sabes que si entra en el `catch` algo salió mal.

*(fíjate que no le puse un try/catch al método `registrarUsuario` porque la va a capturar el llamado en RegistrarUsuarios)*